# Fetching Data which is of String Type From Cloud FireStore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve the time which is of string type from firestore but when i do so i get an error saying .

The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null

```
      : this(
          id: id,
          name: data['name'],
          online: data['online'] && data['state'] != null,
          isOn: (data['state'] != null) ? data['state']['on'] : false,
          time: data['state']['Time'],
        );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Please show where call you ‘fromData’ constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your 'on'(inside of state) get proper.
then you need get 'Time' as same with this condition,

```
    this(
          id: id,
          name: data['name'],
          online: data['online'] && data['state'] != null,
          isOn: (data['state'] != null) ? data['state']['on'] : false,
          time: (data['state'] != null) ? data['state']['Time'] : 'blank or null time text',
        );
```